# Dell laptop stuck and frozen at logo screen

Tags: boot, laptop, dell-inspiron

I have an old inspiron laptop. Today I turned it on however after a while it got stuck in between so I forced a shutdown. However when I turned it back on it got frozen with a broken logo screen at startup.

Comment: What do you mean by Broken?    https://www.startpage.com/do/dsearch?query=Dell+laptop+stuck+and+frozen+at+logo+screen&cat=web&pl=opensearch&language=english

Comment: Old laptop - so maybe the hard drive has failed.  Can you start with the Dell USB hard drive test application?

Comment: Moab By broken I mean it's pixelated. The pixels are spread across the screen. I tried to upload an image however there was some technical issue due to which it failed to upload.

Comment: John. What did you mean by hard drive test application?

Comment: @SanketR All Dell laptops have hardware diagnostics built-in that can be accessed via the boot menu (F12) or by holding down a hotkey while you power the system on (FN by itself, or it's FN + another key, I can't remember).

Comment: Yeah I tried to enter it. But it simply doesn't respond. I am wondering if dust accumulated could be a problem. Recently the cpu temperature used to reach the threshold sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I had a Dell laptop that used to crash on start so I used  to boot  it up  in safe mode and it was fine,if your screen is pixelated from the initial start up or at any other given time  then it could just simply broken. I also had a levno laptop which i thought kept crashing but the screen was broke, I just wired it up to a monitor, then the keyboard and mouse pad broke, so I bought a keyboard and mouse  It was a Frankenstein's monster of a laptop but it worked.

Comment: If the screen was broke ideally the laptop should proceed with the booting up. However it gets stuck up the start. Doesn't go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

https://youtu.be/mt5dMMiTggQ thought this video might be useful, but you've probably tried all this, still puzzled about the pixelated screen, in my case the display was freezing but the system still booted successfully, when I hooked up a monitor it was on the desktop but the laptop screen was froze on start up screen.

Comment: Yeah. I have already tried it. The strange part is the laptop starts for approx 2 seconds and then hangs up. I hear the fans spinning up and then coming to a halt.